# iTunes Connect won't let me create a new version of an existing App

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

When I try to add a new iOS version of an existing App on iTunes Connect, I get the following error: "Your changes couldn't be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us." I've tried lots of various Store Version Numbers, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I can create a tvOS update without a problem, but that still doesn't help with the iOS one.

This has happened on two of my apps that I'd like to update. The problem started a little before the itunesconnect.com downtime around April 22 (which I thought might be causing it).

Anyone run into something similar or know a workaround?

Comment: Do what Apple tells you in the message. It's probably temporary.

Comment: Thanks. I've already sent a request for help to Apple. I'll try again over the next few days.

Comment: Which browser you are using? Try clearing cache of browser and try again? Try other browsers? However use recommended by apple

Comment: I've used all the browsers in both Windows and Mac. Nothing worked. I'm talking with Apple dev support. I think it's a back-end problem.

Comment: Same issue when I try to  "Add iTunes Connect User" gives me "Your changes couldn't be saved. Try again. If the problem persists, contact us." error, I try many random variations, didn't work. Be patient... (April 26-27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple fixed the problem after I submitted a itunesconnect support request. It had to be escalated to the dev group, so it took about a week.

Everything is working now. They didn't say, but my guess is that it was related to trying to create a new build while they were starting maintenance on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and resolved it by logging in with different user and saving new version worked.

[image]